# How do I edit the information in a RandomAccessFile?

Tags: java

I have managed to save two separate pieces of information in the file below. But I would love to know how I can go about editing the info in this file.

```
try {
    RandomAccessFile fileWriter = new RandomAccessFile("Officers.txt", "rw");

    fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length());
    fileWriter.writeUTF(officerObject.getOfficerBadgeNum());
    fileWriter.writeUTF(officerObject.getOfficerFirstName());
    fileWriter.writeUTF(officerObject.getOfficerLastName());
    fileWriter.writeUTF(officerObject.getOfficerPrecint());

    fileWriter.close();
    System.out.println("Data Successfully Saved");
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error in File. Could not SAVE Officer");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: By reading it fully, modifying it, then writing the fully modified data back to the file. Fair enough, you don't need to write the beginning (you can just seek to the place you want to modify), but the end of the file needs to be rewritten fully if the data changes length. E.g. last name changes from "Smith" to "Jorgenson", and you've just overwritten the data for the precinct.

Comment: This code saves four pieces of information, not two. You can't 'edit' any file unless you know where the information to be changed is and the new information is the same length as the old.

Comment: You need to seek to position and write again, but with variable data you risk to overwrite the other data, and to lose the seek index of the next data. Maybe with a protocole implying an array of int at the beginning, but it's up to you to define it. `You expect me to talk Mister Bond?`